# Добаление SSH в DigitalOcean или в созданный Droplet?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Есть ли разница между добавлением SSH в админ панели DigitalOcean или сам закинул на созданный ubuntu server?

Comment: судя по приведённому вами описанию — есть.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы добавите SSH ключ в админке DigitalOcean, то потом при создании нового дроплета, можно будет его выбрать, и он добавится сразу в `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Ручками можно уже после создания дроплета залить другие ключи в `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Если вы просто добавите ключ в админку, он для уже созданных серверов не станет работать автоматически.